# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: “” error android

Tags: java, android

I am making an app where user must enter basic info about self.First name,second name, city and quantity that he or she wish to order.If he or she  skip one field toast will pop up with message what field is skipped. And that is ok.That works, but if he skips quantity field I got error on my phone and it send user back on previously activity.When I inspect my LogCat I see error message

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: “” error
```

Now I know why that message appears.Because it expected to find Integer,in if statment. but actually finds String. But do not know how to fix it.The last if/else statemen is an Issue:

Now what i tried so far:

```
1) Tried to set primitive int as object Integer 
2)Tried to use kolicina==0; 
3)Tried to use kolicina.equals(null) / kolicina.equals(0); 
4)Tried to use .isEmty();
```

my code:

```
package com.dsk.android.decijisvetknjiga;

import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.EditText;

import android.widget.Toast;



public class Narudzbina extends AppCompatActivity {

   String porukaGreska="";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.narudzbina);

    }
    public boolean praznoPolje(EditText et){
        return (et != null && (et.equals("") || et.equals(" ")));
    }

    public void kreiranjeNarudzbine(View v) {
        EditText editTextIme = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ime);
        String imeNarucioca = editTextIme.getText().toString();
        praznoPolje(editTextIme);


        EditText editTextPrezime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.prezime);
        String prezimeNarucioca = editTextPrezime.getText().toString();
        praznoPolje(editTextIme);

        EditText editTelefonNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.telefon);
        String telefonNarucioca = editTelefonNarucioca.getText().toString();
        praznoPolje(editTelefonNarucioca);

        EditText editAdresaNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.adresa);
        String adresaNarucioca = editAdresaNarucioca.getText().toString();
        praznoPolje(editAdresaNarucioca);

        EditText editGradNarucioca = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.grad);
        String gradNarucioca = editGradNarucioca.getText().toString();
        praznoPolje(editGradNarucioca);

        EditText editKolicina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kolicina);
        String narucenaKolicina = editKolicina.getText().toString();
        int kolicina = Integer.parseInt(narucenaKolicina);

        praznoPolje(editKolicina);
        int cenaNarudzbine = cena(kolicina);

        String poruka = sumiranjeNarudzbine(imeNarucioca, prezimeNarucioca, telefonNarucioca, adresaNarucioca, gradNarucioca, cenaNarudzbine);
        Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        smsIntent.putExtra("address", "+1111111");
        smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", poruka);

        if(imeNarucioca!=null && imeNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Unesite ime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(prezimeNarucioca!=null && prezimeNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite Prezime", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        else if(telefonNarucioca!=null && telefonNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite kontakt telefon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(adresaNarucioca!=null && adresaNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this,"Unesite adresu",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(gradNarucioca!=null && gradNarucioca.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Navedite grad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if(narucenaKolicina!=null && narucenaKolicina.equals("")){
            Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Navedite zeljenu kolicinu", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            startActivity(smsIntent);
        }
    }
```

English is not my native language so do apologize for spelling mistakes or some lack of clarity in the matter, I'd be happy to explain it if necessary.

Comment: `“”` <- is this the actual value of `narucenaKolicina`? If so, then this is your problem. Those look like some UTF-Characters and are certainly no digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is on this line

```
int kolicina = Integer.parseInt(narucenaKolicina);
```

If the input is empty, it will try to parse an empty string "".  You need to wrap this in an if statement to check if narucenaKolicina is empty or a valid int before you try to parse it.

Answer (score 0):

Tip for you to ignore this exeception:

```
EditText editKolicina = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kolicina);
String narucenaKolicina = editKolicina.getText().toString();
if(!narucenaKolicina.isEmpty())
    int kolicina = Integer.parseInt(narucenaKolicina);
else
    Toast.makeText(Narudzbina.this, "Don't leave this field empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is caused by the `parseInt()` method so change kolicina to integer is not useful

You should try something like this :

```
if (narucenaKolicina != null && !narucenaKolicina.toString().trim().equals(""))
```

As condition to avoid "" string.

Comment: no it says operands '!=' cannot be applied to 'int' ,'null'. Also toString() is  red and show error cannot resolve toString() Metod

Comment: The problem is the value in NarucenaKolicina so you should check that..

Comment: nothing change,still getting the same error i am going to try to put null instead of " " or to put 0 if that doesn't work..

Comment: Use can use  TextUtils.isEmpty(narucenaKolicina)

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your string have empty text, not only null value or 0.
You have to do something like this

```
kolicina.equals("");
```